# IP from multi gateway, openvz debian

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, openvz

I have a problem with network in my dedicated server.

I have a host:

```
ip 188.60.240.71 
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway 188.60.240.1
broadcast 188.60.240.127
network 188.60.240.0
```

I order additional ipv4 to config openvz virtual machine.
I get 5 ip in other gateway:

```
ip 188.60.240.[224-228]
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway 188.60.240.129
broadcast 188.60.240.255
network 188.60.240.128
```

How to config network to handle this ip and assign it to my openvz to work?

Answer (score 0):

These addresses are from other subnets. So they won't work directly. You can:

1. Configure dedicated server as router (it will be complicated).
2. Merge these subnets into single network (very simple, but not always possible for some reasons outside this topic eg. extra payments).

Answer (score 0):

Were you told to apply these settings on the same network interface (e.g. `eth0`) or did you receive a separate new one?

Either way, you'll just have to configure the new settings but omit the default gateway, and see if it works - if 188.60.240.1 and 188.60.240.129 are both aware that both sets of traffic are legitimately originating from your machine, they'll route your packets regardless of which outgoing address or interface you use. If it doesn't work, you'll have to set up source-based policy routing, so that each piece of traffic goes through its own default gateway interface.